# mailto registry association key?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, xml

I'm banging my head against a brick wall trying to define mailto association to Outlook 2016 for our domain. (2012r2 and win10 1903)

Regardless of what I try, deploying a .xml file that was generated on a target machine doesn't work. I even set it up as a local GPO and it still has no effect.

I posted way more info at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc3e1950-8d79-4fe5-a8ff-8f8ff8c98478/file-association-xml-file-does-not-work-on-1903?forum=winserverGP

Is there a registry key in Windows 10 1903 that I could manually define so as to associate the mailto protocol away from Windows 10 Mail and onto Outlook 2016?

I tried a couple of them but Windows immediately reverted stuff back...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was an other GPO conflicting with this one, somehow I didn't notice that in RSOP when I double checked.

It also turns out that the xml string is the same for both versions of office so that's perfect!